# How can I add the Network Manager Applet to the panel after removing?

Tags: gnome, panel, network-manager

In rearranging the panel, I removed the Network Manager Applet. I tried to add it back, but it doesn't show up in the list (Add To Panel). I can start it up and see it as a running process (nm-applet), and I'm still connected to the internets, but I don't know how to get the panel icon back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add the Notification Area applet to the panel. The network manager will show up there.

Answer (score 5):

```
System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications
```

Check "Network Manager"

If it's not in the list then add `nm-applet --sm-disable`