# Few GUI problems with minimal install

Tags: configuration, network-manager, gwibber, ubuntu-minimal, gksu

I installed a minimal Ubuntu with a complete and functional GUI, but facing a few problems:

- nm-applet's icon won't show in the notification area, but I can connect to wired internet fine. I am not able to configure my wireless or VPN this way.
- gksu's authentication screen is different from the usual graphical authentication - the screen turns gray as usual, but there are more options like save password for this session or keyring. And most importantly, **it won't accept my password no matter what**.
- And lastly, Gwibber seems to install no matter what, but there's not a single package in my knowledge that I installed has anything related to Gwibber.

I would welcome any help regarding these three issues. I did not mention what packages I installed, because the list is long, but I will do so if anyone requests.

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

As you can see from the solution I posted, the problems are pretty much solved. However, I'd love to know what exactly hrhnick's solution did and the possible workarounds to the Gwibber issue.

Comment: Additionally, if anyone can tell me how to install restricted drivers on command line, instead of having to install jockey-gtk it will be extremely welcome.

Comment: You should write one post per question as they are not related, and it's hart to answer/accept multiple questions.

Comment: Experiences in minimal install among general Ubuntu users is very low. So I wrote one post for all the problems I had relating to minimal, and if anyone knows what to do will hopefully will reply.

Comment: @Toki If you split your questions up into three different question topics you will get more authoritative responses from the people who know each component.

Comment: Running `gconftool-2 -s --type bool  /apps/gksu/sudo-mode  true` should fix the gksu issue.

Comment: @hrhnick, sorry for the late reply, but can you elaborate as to what exactly it does? And it would be great if you replied as an answer, since you'll get points, and I'll get notified as well. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nm-applet problem solved, Paul Crowley came up with [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4360/no-network-manager-icon-in-the-notification-area-so-i-cant-use-my-vpn-connectio/4373#4373):

```
sudo stop gdm
sudo stop network-manager
sudo ifdown eth0
sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces # comment out eth0 entry
sudo start network-manager
sudo start gdm
```

Regarding the Gwibber issue, [Paqman on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10206337&postcount=11) clarified that the indicator-me package for Me Menu in Maverick is responsible for a recommended package dependency on Gwibber.

As hrhnick suggested in the comments, executing the command `gconftool-2 -s --type bool /apps/gksu/sudo-mode true` solves the gksu issue.