# Can't add NetworkManager applet to gnome panel

Tags: network-manager, gnome-panel, applet

I have researched this problem extensively and I can't seem to find an answer. In Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, I want to connect to my VPN through the NetworkManager applet. I installed all the network manager packages, including the gnome client.

I understand I need to add the "Notification Area" to the panel, which I have done. I checked that the NetworkManager is running:

```
nate@nate-desktop:~$ service network-manager status
network-manager start/running, process 763
```

In /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf, I have added managed=true (don't know    if this matters, but I saw it suggested on one forum):

```
nate@nate-desktop:~$ more /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf 
# This file is installed into /etc/NetworkManager, and is loaded by 
# NetworkManager by default.  To override, specify: '--config file' 
# during NM startup.  This can be done by appending to DAEMON_OPTS in 
# the file:
#
# /etc/default/NetworkManager
#

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
#managed=false
managed=true
```

I restarted NetworkManager and tried rebooting, too.  At this point, it looks like NetworkManager is running but it's not appearing in the NotificationArea of the panel. I don't know what else to try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to start the network manager applet.  It's started by default, although it sounds like you've done some customisation.  Here's a screenshot of my entry :

[image]

This is available through system/preferences/startup applications.

Answer (score 1):

Network Manager is a separate beast from its applet for good reason: Network Manager is a daemon that persists outside of X. The applet just communicates with this daemon.

Anyway, you want to run this:

```
nm-applet --sm-disable
```

It's set to run on boot on my computer from System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting you right, your `network-manager` wasn't installed by default. It's the same case with Ubuntu minimal installs (which I've tried), and installing it later doesn't make the `nm-applet` appear in the notification area. I've found the answer to this problem on [Ask Ubuntu itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4360/no-network-manager-icon-in-the-notification-area-so-i-cant-use-my-vpn-connectio/4373#4373):

`sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces` or `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

In the first command, an editor in the Terminal itself appears. Otherwise, you may use `gedit` as in the second command or replace it with your preferred text editor. Once the file is open, find your network interfaces, like eth0 or something and add `#` in front of the line it's mentioned. Reboot and the network manager's icon should appear normally in the notification area.

Comment: For a graphical text editor like Gedit, `gksu` (or `gksudo`) should be used instead of straight `sudo`, [to avoid breaking things](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).