# network-manager applet does not detect internet connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, gui

I have been testing out connman, the alternative connection manager. While testing connman, I had to remove my network manager. I did an

```
apt-get purge network-manager*
```

Now, when I reinstalled the network manager and all its dependencies, including network-manager-gnome, I cannot see it on the panel however, the internet is connected through ethernet. I can access the internet on the browser and also connect vpnc through the cli. but the GUI does not recognize it. Any idea how to get the GUI recognize the eth0?

Adding screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

Comment: Have you unplugged your Ethernet cable and rebooted, then configured your wireless?

Comment: its ethernet cable only. no wireless. as i said, i can get internet connection but its not displayed through the network-manager applet on the panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4360/no-network-manager-icon-in-the-notification-area-so-i-cant-use-my-vpn-connectio/4373#4373) suggests.

Long answer short, open `/etc/network/interfaces` in a text editor, `sudo` mode, and comment out the `eth0` and whatever network interfaces you want to control on `network-manager`.

Comment: one thing i would like to add here is that, if i do this change, then i will not be able to get internet from the cli. doing ifconfig after this change will only show up the local adapter.

Comment: What do you mean? `ifconfig` shows all the network adapters regardless of it being commented out on the `interfaces` file.

Comment: your suggestion worked out perfectly fine. Please ignore my previous comment. It has brought back my network-manager-gui detection. Also, ifconfig is now showing all the adapters and i can connect to my vpn as well!! A million thanks to you man!!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I faced this issue when experimenting with minimal installs. Many thanks to the original author of the solution I linked.

Comment: I have the same issue with a ppp0 connection, I tried your suggestion but there was no ppp0 line to comment out. Is there anything else to be tried?

Comment: @boywithaxe I'm sorry I can't help you there. You'd be better off asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this resolved it.
If you have the package `connman` installed, try removing it, and rebooting.

Comment: connman gets remove when you reinstall network-manager

Comment: Blah... there goes my idea. Hope you are able to get it sorted out Ubuntuser.